Check from a firebase cloud function quota data
Is there a way to check from a firebase cloud function (using firebase CLI I guess) my current quota data (number of read/write/deletes of my project in the current day). The idea is that I have some batch house keeping to do that is non-critical (it could be done any day) in my firestore database. I would like to deploy some cloud function that does this and schedule it daily before the end of the day. But ideally I want it to be done only if the quota limits are not reached to pay as little as possible. So I want to first check my quota data (how many write/reads/deletes has my project done so far that day) programmatically and if it's below the free tier limits, perform the transactions.
Is this possible?
Thanks
I tried searching for an answer, including the firebase CLI reference documentation, but all I get is to check the console, but I want a programmatic solution

As you have discovered from reviewing the documentation for the CLI, it's not possible.  You can file a feature request on firebase-tools GitHub, and also reach out to Firebase support to explain your use case.
